# Automatically start multiple user sessions when OSX starts

Tags: macos, automator, login

I need to get several users session logged-in as soon as the computer starts. Manually I would have to log into the first user and then start switching to each one to open their respective sessions. I need to automate this process. At the end sessions must remain open so each will have some program instances running.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the specific need? Maybe there's some terminal option, I'm assuming they don't have to be aigned in GUI-vise since you can only use one user at once anyways?

Comment: Yes they need to be individual user interactive sessions since they will be remotely accessed by users via VNC

Comment: Put the stuff you want to start up in the users login items?

Comment: Yes that's already done but if the machine reboots I need to manually login to every one of the 20+ users to open the sessions. Users do not login directly to the machine they use the session via browser.

Comment: What kind of session are we talking about here. If they use standard screensharing to log in to a user the login items will be triggered.

Comment: Yes but they do not actually login. the session must be open since we stream a portion of the desktop over HTTP using VNC. It all works but every time the machine reboots all user sessions need to be manually opened. For practical purposes the end user doesn't even know is a desktop he only interacts with one particular software instance within a session via web browser.

Comment: @SebKe; did you find a good solution for this? I have about the exact same requirement now. I need to start some applications on seperate users "desktops" on boot.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there are no passwords, you can have each user session open another one when starting, using CGSession. I did not try it with Yosemite, but it does work for me with El Capitan.

1. Log in as user1.
2. Create an empty file named “logall.sh”, in a folder where the user won’t see it.
3. Make the file executable (open Applications/Utilities/Terminal, type `chmod 777`  (with the trailing space); drag the file’s icon in the Terminal window; press <kbd>Return</kbd>).
4. Make the file always open with Terminal (right-click on the file’s icon; select “Open with…/Other”; check “Always open with”; select Applications/Utilities/Terminal).
5. Open the file in TextEdit.
6. Set the file’s contents to the following, and save:

   ```
   "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/\
   CGSession" -switchToUserID `id -u user2`
   ```

Repeat for each user except user1. Set user1 to log in automatically on startup (System Preferences/Users and Groups/Options/Automatic login/user1).